# Saving user input text containing an apostrophe into a database table using $wpdb->insert

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, escaping

I am using Wordpress and MySQL.
I have a simple form to allow a user to enter a text string. In this case I am asking for the name of a Vendor. So let's say the user enters "Arby's".  Arby's contains an apostrophe. After the user submit's the form I use $wpdb->insert to insert it into my custom table in the database. The result I get is:

ID   meta_key   meta_value
13   vendor     Arby\'s

I don't know how to get rid of the "\". The user did not enter a "\". And of course I don't want it in the database value. I just want it as the user entered it - "Arby's".  I have spent a lot of time researching this and have tried numerous things that I have found but nothing works. Here is a stripped down version of my code to demonstrate my issue and what I have tried.
...

```
global $wpdb;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $vendor = $_POST['vendor'];
    $vendor1 = addslashes($_POST['vendor']);
    $vendor2 = esc_attr($_POST['vendor']);
    $vendor3 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['vendor']);
    $vendor4 = esc_html_e($_POST['vendor']);

    echo '<br><br>Post Value: ' . $_POST['vendor'] . '<br>';
    echo 'With Addslashes: ' . $vendor1 . '<br>';
    echo 'With esc_attr: ' . $vendor2 . '<br>';
    echo 'With sanitize_test_field: ' . $vendor3 . '<br>';
    echo 'With esc_html_e: ' . $vendor4 . '<br>';

    $result = $wpdb->insert( 'raw_meta',
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'vendor',
            'meta_value' => $vendor,
        )
    );

} else {
    echo '<form method="post" >';
        echo 'Vendor Name:<br>';
        echo '<input style="font-size:18px;" type="text" name="vendor" autofocus required><br><br>';
        echo '<input type="submit"  value="Save New Vendor" name="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

...
The code echos the following:

```
Post Value: Arby\'s
With Addslashes: Arby\\\'s
With esc_attr: Arby\'s
With sanitize_test_field: Arby\'s
With esc_html_e:
```

I have tried other things as well but nothing gives me the results I am looking for. This seems like such a basic thing; accepting input from a form and storing in the database as is was entered. But I can't figure out why it is not working. If you have a solution I would love to hear it. But in addition to just the answer to this specific problem if there is a resource for understanding this issue and learning how to deal with it that would be great. I have not been in a classroom and just self taught so just don't understand this topic.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I never got help on this but I finally happened across how to solve my problem. So what was happening is that the posting of the form added a slash () before the apostrophes. I was thinking it was the $wpdb->insert that was the issue but not so.

How I solved my problem is using the code below. First I found the stripslashes function that removed the slashes that the form post put in. Then, I had to use __() as well. Not really sure why but it worked.

```
    $translated = __( stripslashes( $_POST['vendor'] ) );

    $result = $wpdb->insert( 'raw_meta',
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'test_data',
            'meta_value' => $translated,
        )
    );
```